# Difficulty Locating Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 After Installation (Checked all Directories)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I recently installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 on my computer (64b), but I am facing challenges when trying to locate the application and related files. Despite the successful installation, I cannot find the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 in any of the usual locations.

This is causing difficulties as I need to access the application to connect to an Access database and utilize its features (specifically trying to reference it, using VBA code) I have searched through my system, but I am unable to locate the installed program. Any guidance on how to locate the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 installation or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Specifically, I've been trying to set a connection link within VBA. here's my code.

```
Dim qt As QueryTable 
Set qt = targetWorkbook.Sheets("qry_ABB1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _ 
  "ODBC;DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" & _ 
  "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName, _ 
  Destination:=targetWorkbook.Sheets("qry_ABB1").Range("A1"))
```

However, right now it is saying there is no driver, even though I installed it. I asked ChatGPT what the problem is and they said I need to find the data source for the Database Engine but I can't find it.

Comment: This would not be a "program" so much as a "library". Have you looked in your References in your vba project? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/How-to/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference (You don't necessarily need the database engine - depending on what you mean by "connect to an Access database and utilize its features")

Comment: @topsail yes, but dont i need to reference the pathway using a .aacdb in vba?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't know what you mean by reference the pathway. You can connect to Access databases using ADO or DAO - run queries, update data. I assume you can "open" an access database using the runtime redistributable.

Comment: Please don't post code in as comment. Edit your question and put the code there - and don't forget to format it as code so that it is readable.

Comment: @FunThomas Sorry. Edited post.

Comment: @topsail Edited post for further information.

Comment: I tested code and it works - connection is created. Are you able to manually create connection? Are you able to manually open Access database?

Comment: *right now it is saying there is no driver, even though I installed it* what driver did you install?